# Sum pairs that are divisible

Tags: java

Given input array `ar = [1,2,3,4,5]`, and `k=5`, find divisible sum pairs such that elements in input array when added give the result `k`.

Sample output - Three pairs meeting the criteria in this case are `[1,4], [2,3], and [4,6]`.

Here is my code -

```
public class DivisibleSumPairs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArr = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        List<Integer> output = divisibleSumPairs(inputArr, 5);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<Integer> divisibleSumPairs(int[] inputArr, int input) {
        List<Integer> output = null;
        List<Integer> outputLst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < inputArr.length; j++) {
                if ((inputArr[i] + inputArr[j]) % input == 0) {
                    output = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);
                    output.add(inputArr[i]);
                    output.add(inputArr[j]);
                    outputLst.addAll(output);
                }
            }
        }
        return outputLst;
    }

}
```

The output result for my code is - `[1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 4]` while I want to group it into sub arrays having two elements - `[1,4], [2,3], and [4,6]`. Any tips on how to achieve this.

Comment: what do you expect `outputLst.addAll(output);` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired output you need `List<List<Integer>>` rather than `List<Integer>`. So, you should replace the following line:

```
List<Integer> outputLst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

with

```
List<List<Integer>> outputLst = new ArrayList<>();
```

And inside your loop, replace the following line:

```
outputLst.addAll(output);
```

with:

```
outputLst.add(output);
```

And I have just realized that you will also need to update your nested `for` loop because of a logical error. From:

```
for (int j = 1; j < inputArr.length; j++)
```

to:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < inputArr.length; j++)
```

You can see the working code [here](http://ideone.com/S4buFt).